# Can input type = hidden be used to send information to a server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have

```
<input type="hidden" name="Content" id="Content_m">
```

Can I send a specific text to the server ? If so, is it done by adding a value field to form field?

Comment: Any input with a name attribute will be sent to the server by the browser. Hidden inputs included. The value attribute will be used as a default unless the user changes it – keep in mind that they can do so.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but you can send the value of a hidden input to the server in the same way you send the value of a text input.

Comment: Can the user himself add a value field and send it back to the server?

Comment: Yes. I can POST whatever data I want to whatever URL, it's the server that is responsible for handling that data and responding appropriately.

Comment: You mean, can I, as a user, tamper with the page to add a value to that field so that it gets sent to the server? Yes.

Comment: in this case, if input is hidden, user just does not see input, so he can't change the value as usual

Comment: But if the input field is hidden, how would I submit the value?

Comment: Well, you could open up your javascript console and type `document.getElementById('Content_m').value = "whatever I want";`, or you could even use a tool like Fiddler to intercept the request and tamper with it that way.

Comment: @zack, do you have user value somewhere is JS code? what is the source of value to be posted?

Comment: it has to be inputted by the user. It isn't stored.

Comment: Are you the user in this situation, or are you the developer attempting to defend against this?

Comment: The user. I am trying to send the text. But I am not quite sure if its being actually sent because I don't see the desired result. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are attempting to do something the developer didn't intend, the code on the server may be protecting against your tampering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Content" id="Content_m" value="your_text">
```

Answer (score 2):

yes. to send info use value field like so:

```
<input type="hidden" value="iwanttosendthis" name="Content" id="Content_m">
```

Answer (score 2):

Hidden inputs are submitted with the form as normal inputs.

You can retrieve whatever value the hidden input contained from (for example) $_POST in PHP:

```
$myVar = $_POST["Content"]
```